# Themes, Styles OR hardcode?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I have an application with 7 activity. All activity has 1, 2, 3 or 4 `root` element in a `main root` element. This `root` element have a dark background color with relevant color. I want have a light theme in my app. Therefore I want to know which way is better and professional to change the my app theme from dark to light?

- Define two theme with my color value for each `root` element? if answer is yes, How can I define it? example code?
- Define style for each `root` element?
- Or simply find my 1, 2, 3 or 4 `root` element and change background color with Options menu setting UI?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Themes are styles too so if you want that your whole application driven from for example Holo.light you can simply define a style like below and change your desired colors and style for predefined elements , then set your app theme in Manifest:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Inverse</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyleSmall">@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small.Inverse</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyleLarge">@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large.Inverse</item>
</style>
```

but if you want set a background color for your Activities and change it on runtime or by clicking menuItem , i think better approach is define two styles for your root elements(Most outer Elements in Activities Layouts) and define Background for those elements like :

```
<style name="LinearLayoutLight">
    <item name="android:background">@color/#somecolor</item>
</style>

<style name="LinearLayoutDark">
    <item name="android:background">@color/#somecolor</item>
</style>
```

Comment: @SamanMoradiZiarani : dear saman ty for accepting , for your first question u define a style in style.xml then in your Activity layout use : style="@style/yourstyle" in your root element. for changing theme at runtime here in stackOverFlow you can find nice answers.it's too broad to answer it hear.

Comment: @SamanMoradiZiarani : create another style with background Item , then assign that style to those Elements.

Comment: @SamanMoradiZiarani : why do you repeating Accepting an unAccepting the answer!!?